# Google docs API v3: Updating a document removes it from shared folder

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

When I upload a new revision of a document (using the odt format), it is removed from all shared folders.

I'm using OAuth 1 and a ruby client, but it also occurs in the OAuth playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

The flow:

1. (Create a text document and put it in a shared folder)
2. Get the document entry: `GET /feeds/default/private/full/<docid>`.

   It should have a 'shared' label and a link to the folder in #parent
3. Get the upload link for the document (link @rel~=#resumable-edit-media):

   `PUT https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/document%3A<docid>`

   As I'm not changing any document meta, the body of this request is empty
4. Upload document body to `response.location`
5. The resulting document is not in the shared folder, does not have a `shared` label or a `#parent` link.

Is this by design? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this using the Java API, it didn't happen until a few days ago. It looks like a regression but since the documents list api is deprecated, I fear it might not be fixed :(

Comment: By the way, my workaround was to save the list of parent folders before updating the document, and move the document to the original folders after updating. Ugly but it works :P

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the client library adding some fields to your requests or resetting all those you didn't specify.

I'd recommend upgrading to the Drive API and use the code in the reference guide to update an existing file and create a new revision:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

Comment: I don't think that's the case - the same occurs when using the OAuth playground, where I control the headers and request body directly.

As to upgrading to the Drive API, we're going to do it eventually, but as it requires switching to OAuth 2 it will not happen immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your PUT in step 3 should be a POST. Not sure if this is significant or not.